# sed: filter string subset from lines matching regexp

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sed, scripting

I have a file of the following format:

```
abc: A B C D E
abc: 1 2 3 4 5 
def  D E F G H
def: 10 11 12 23 99
...
```

That is a first line with strings after ':' is a header for the next line with numbers. I'd like to use `sed` to extract only a line starting with `PATTERN` string with numbers in the line.

Number of numbers in a line is variable, but assume that I know exactly how many I'm expecting, so I tried this command:

```
% sed 's/^abc: \([0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+\)$/\1/g' < file.txt
```

But it dumps all entries from the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sed` does substitutions and prints each line, whether a substitution happens or not.
2. Your regular expression is wrong. It would match only three numbers separated by spaces if extended regex flag was given (`-E`). Without it, not even that, because the `+` sign will be interpreted literally.
3. The best here is to use addresses and only print lines that have a match:

```
sed -nE '/^abc: [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+$/p' < file.txt
```

or better,

```
sed -nE '/^abc:( [0-9]+){5}$/p' < file.txt
```

The `-n` flag disables the "print all lines" behavior of `sed` described in (1). Only the lines that reach the `p` command will be printed.

Comment: thanks for comment. `sed -nE '/^abc: ([0-9]+ ){5}$/p' < file.txt` would only work if the last number in the line also end with space character?

Comment: I put the space _in front_ of the numbers, assuming there's always a space after the `:` and between numbers: `sed -En '/abc:( [0-9]+)+/p' file.txt` (you don't need the `<` redirection, sed reads from a file if given a filename)

Comment: @Mark True, I've corrected it, but now it won't match if there is a space after the last number. You may adapt that regex to your needs. Specially, consider adding a `[ \t]*` before `$` if you want to allow extra spaces and tabs.

Comment: @StephenP Yeah, `<` is disposable here. With `<`, the shell opens the file and without it `sed` will do.

Comment: @Quasímodo, @Stephen P,  thanks for your comments, it works now. If I want to just extract the matched numbers (and remove prefix, e.g, abc), does the following command look OK for you?   `sed -n 's/^abc: \([0-9].*\)/\1/p'`

Comment: @Mark - that _does_ work for me, but be careful … using the `.*` there will allow _any_ character, for example the line `abc: 1 c9 A 7f` would be included and printed as `1 c9 A 7f`

Answer (score 1):

*to extract only a line starting with PATTERN string with numbers in the line* and *Number of numbers in a line is variable* means at least one number, so:

```
$ sed -n '/abc: \([0-9]\+\)/p' file
```

Output:

```
abc: 1 2 3 4 5
```

With exactly 5 numbers, use:

```
$ sed -n '/abc: \([0-9]\+\( \|$\)\)\{5\}/p' file
```

Comment: Strangely, your two patterns aren't working for me on macOS although looking at them they _should_ — but they _do_ work on linux, and they work on macOS if I add `-E` and remove the `\\`es

Comment: Yeah, GNU rot .

Answer (score 1):

With @Mark's additional question in a comment *"If I want to just extract the matched numbers (and remove prefix, e.g, abc)…"* this is the pattern I came up with:

```
sed -En 's/^abc: (([0-9]+[ \t]?)+)[ \t]*$/\1/gp' file.txt
```

I'm using the `-E` flag for extended regular expressions to avoid all the escaping that would be needed.
Given this file:

```
abc: A B C D E
abc: 1 2 3 4 5 
abc: 1 c9 A 7f
def  D E F G H
def: 10 11 12 23 99
```

… this regex matches `abc: 1 2 3 4 5` while excluding `abc: 1 c9 A 7f` — it also allows variable whitespace and trailing whitespace.

Comment: thanks, it works for me. One more thing though: it turns out that I may have negative numbers in the line, so I updated your expression like this:  `sed -En 's/^abc: (([-]?[0-9]+[ \t]?)+)[ \t]*$/\1/gp'`

Comment: BTW I tried to remove '-E' argument and escape all parentheses, and it didn't work for me. It just didn't return anything. I'm using GNU sed- 4.2.2 on ubuntu.

Comment: @Mark without the `-E` you also have to escape the plus "one-or-more" `\+` and, I'm pretty sure, the question mark "optional" `\?` (but can't try it at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

With any sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/^abc: \([0-9 ]*\)$/\1/p' file
1 2 3 4 5
```